# Using COM DLL from Python

Tags: python, dll, com, pywin32

I have a DLL, it is an SDK for the Pastel Partner accounting system. Using Dependency Walker I can see that the DLL has the following methods: DllRegisterServer, DllUnregisterServer, DllGetClassObject

With the library there came a sample VB program that referenced the DLL and instantiated it like this:

```
Dim SDK As New PasSDK.PastelPartnerSDK
```

The only way I've been able to use this library from python is to register it with Windows:

```
regsvr32 PasSDK.dll
```

And then use it in python like this:

```
import win32com.client
sdk = win32com.client.Dispatch("PasSDK.PastelPartnerSDK")
sdk.SetLicense(...)
etc...
```

However, is there a way to use this library directly without registering it first? Something like:

```
from ctypes import *
sdk = cdll.LoadLibrary('PasSDK.dll')
```

When I do this I can see that sdk.DllGetClassObject is a function, but how do I instantiate it like the VB program, is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You'll find the same issue no matter the language you use.  That is, with VB, you'd have to register the component as well.

However, you can use [registration free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) for this purpose.  Create a manifest for the EXE (e.g. python.exe or your app's EXE name) that depends on a manifest which declares the classes, interfaces and/or type libraries it provides.